# Add overlay over image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put an overlay over an image. The image is a background image. The overlay works, but it covers more than only the image.

This is what my should webpage looks like:

1. Text & Navbar
2. Overlay
3. Image

But the page now looks like this:

1. Overlay
2. Text & Navbar
3. Image

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image-main">
    <?php include 'navbar.php'; ?>
    <div class="index-front">
         text
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 .image-main {
    background-image: url('/img/background.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.index-front {
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    z-index: 4;
}

.overlay {
    background-color: #333;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    opacity: 0.75;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

I've tried messing around with the `z-index`, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Try setting the z-index to -1 on your overlay

Comment: can you post a working jsfiddle so that it can help us to work on it

Comment: @DrinkinPeople which class'/id's z-index should I set to -1?

Comment: I suspect ID `#index-front` will give you headaches at some point. You started well using classes. Do so for your `index-front`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan fixed.

Comment: *"`but it covers more than only the image.`"* I'm sure you can do best at explaining your issue. It's not clear how it should look like... cause I see no issue in your example.... (beside the overlay covers your "text")

Comment: Also I'm quite sure that by placing the HTML elements in the right order, you don't need `z-index` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` and `overflow: hidden;`.

```
.image-main {
  background-image: url('/img/background.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
 }

 .index-front {
   margin-top: 50px;
   text-align: center;
   display: block;
   color: #CCCCCC;
   z-index: 4;
      position: relative;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/rxf3rnyy/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.image-main {
  background-image: url('/img/background.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.overlay {
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  opacity: 0.75;
  z-index: -1;
}
.index-front {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: red;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-main">
  <?php include 'navbar.php'; ?>

  <div class="index-front">
    text
  </div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Do you want something like this?

Change `z-index` values

Comment: I want the overlay to only cover the image, not the text. The height of the image and overlay is set with a jQuery function btw.

Comment: `<div class="imageDiv"><img/></div>` you're closing a `<img>` tag, but you never opened one.

Comment: The example works, but on my own page the overlay is behind the image I think.

Comment: @bramhaag Don't tell anything when you are not sure. Make sure where overlay is

Answer (score 0):

First if you want your overlay to only cover the .image-main div then you will want to set this div to have a position of relative.  Then to be safe give it a z-index of 1.  Then set your .overlay div to have a z-index of -1 so it stacks behind everything in the div.  Like so:

Note: I set the .image-main div to have a height so you can see it better.

here is a fiddle to show you [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/dv61633f/)

```
 .image-main {
    background-image: url('/img/background.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 500px;
}

.overlay {
    background-color: #333;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    opacity: 0.75;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

in **css**-

```
.image-main {
background-image: url('/img/background.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
transition: all 0.2s ease;
position:relative;
}
.showPart{
  position:absolute;top:2px;z-index:3;
}
.overlay {
background-color: #333;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
opacity: 0.75;
z-index: 2;
}
#index-front {
margin-top: 50px;
text-align: center;
display: block;
color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

in **html**

```
<div class="image-main">
  <div class="showPart">
    <?php include 'navbar.php'; ?>
    <div id="index-front">
         text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Edit showPart class width and height as your needed

Comment: Thanks, this works, but it adds a black space (around 140 px) at the top of the page.

Comment: My answer related to only image-main class(div). It never create any black space. You should review your css. That can help you